# Android fragment transition - avoiding GC during animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, garbage-collection, android-animation

I'm using a standard slide animation defined in XML to animate fragment transitions.  Most of these fragments contain ListViews (But not always). 90% of the time, the animation is smooth and flows nicely. Every once in a while, there's a stutter. Checking logcat, there's always a GC happening when a stutter occurs:

```
D/dalvikvm(26619): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 300K, 9% free 13820K/15044K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
```

(It seems weird that it felt like it needed to GC just for 300 KB)

Is there anyway to avoid that GC during an animation (Before or after is fine). Calling System.gc() before the animation is not a great option, especially since there's no guarantee as to when that garbage collection will take place. Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: I think you can't prevent the GC from running. What you can do is try to allocate less objects. I believe there is a video from Google IO from 2012 or 2013 that this subject is presented for game developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question... if the problem is that your animations are janky, then you should be asking "*How can I take a deeper look into what is actually going on?*" A few `GC_FOR_ALLOC` logs in your logcat is not enough information to analyze this issue. And if your app is suffering from performance at times, it is not because you forgot to call `System.gc()`, trust me. :)

Obviously the best way to avoid garbage collection is to reduce the amount of object allocations in your application... that's a given. You can use the "Allocation Tracker" provided in DDMS to further analyze these issues if these problems are not immediately obvious.

I would also recommend watching these videos... they are *really* good, and give you a much deeper understanding of how Android's graphics rendering pipeline works (Romain Guy and Chet Haase are hilarious too :P).

- [For Butter or Worse: Smoothing Out Performance in Android UIs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8m9sHdyXnE)
- [Android Graphics Performance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQZFaec9NpA).

Finally, I recommend using the tools in "Settings --> Developer Options" to your advantage. Check out [this blog post](http://www.curious-creature.org/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html) by Romain Guy for more information (note that the post is a little out dated... as of 4.3 the tools have become a lot easier to work with... they talk about the changes made to these tools in the "Android Graphics Performance" video linked above). Systrace and/or Profile GPU Rendering are especially useful if your goal is to get your animations at or below 60fps.

Comment: One nice thing about systrace in 4.3 is you can add the "dalvik" tag to see the GCs and thread suspensions represented in the trace.